# Are dynamic defaults possible with kvoptions?

Tags: package-writing, kvoptions

I'm writing a package with two options; one of the defaults should change, depending on the other option. Currently, the definitions are:

```
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=gitlog,prefix=gitLog@}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{write}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{nowrite}{write}
\DeclareStringOption{bibfile}
```

Now, if the user provides either the `write` or the `nowrite` option, I want to obey that rigorously. If, however, neither option is given, then I want to default to `write` if `bibfile` is empty and `nowrite` otherwise.

My starter attempt is this (using xstring):

```
\IfStrEq{}{\gitLog@bibfile}{%
    \renewcommand{\gitLog@bibfile}{\jobname}
}{
    \somehowsetoption{nowrite} if neither write or nowrite given
}%
```

What's the simplest way to provide the `\somehowsetoption` command(s)? (Please note: changing the `\Declare...`s is OK.

I haven't included an MWE, as I think this is more about "how-to" rather than "what's-wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\AddToKeyvalOption{gitlog}{write}{...}` to define some macro (the same for the `nowrite` option). Then said macro will only be defined if either option has been used and you can test for its existance. Here is a complete example that defines `\gitLog@writeset` *only* if either `write` or `nowrite` has been set (I use `etoolbox` instead of `xstring` – simply because I know it better):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.sty}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions,etoolbox}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=gitlog,prefix=gitLog@}

% write:
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{write}
\AddToKeyvalOption{gitlog}{write}{\def\gitLog@writeset{true}}

% nowrite:
\DeclareComplementaryOption{nowrite}{write}
\AddToKeyvalOption{gitlog}{nowrite}{\def\gitLog@writeset{true}}

% bibfile:
\DeclareStringOption{bibfile}

% process options:
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{gitlog}

% check if write/nowrite has been set:
\ifdef\gitLog@writeset
  {}
  {% write/nowrite option has not been set,
   % set boolean depending on value of \gitLog@bibfile:
    \ifdefempty\gitLog@bibfile
      {\booltrue{gitLog@write}}
      {\boolfalse{gitLog@write}}%
  }

\end{filecontents*}

% \usepackage{foo} % false
\usepackage[bibfile=foo]{foo} % true
% \usepackage[nowrite,bibfile=foo]{foo} % false
% \usepackage[write]{foo} % true

\begin{document}

\ifbool{gitLog@write}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I took the liberty of fixing one small, though important, bug. (:-))

Comment: @Brent.Longborough you're welcome :)