# kvoptions not working in a package setup command

Tags: key-value, kvoptions

I have a short demo using `kvoptions` to provide package options at load time. I wanted to experiment with a package setup command and found that removing the options from the `\usepackage{kvtest}` command and putting them in the `\kvtestsetup{...}` command causes them to be ignored. I have a feeling the solution is probably very simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Here is the sample package file (yes, I know about `\left...\right` but this is a demo):

```
\ProvidesPackage{kvtest}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=kvtest,%
  prefix=kvtest@%
}%

\DeclareBoolOption[false]{boldvectors}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{doublemagbars}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

%\newcommand*{\kvtestsetup}{%
%  \kvsetkeys{kvtest}%
%}%

\typeout{}
\ifkvtest@boldvectors
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get bold vectors.}
  \renewcommand{\vec}{\symbfit}
\else
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get arrowed vectors.}
\fi

\ifkvtest@doublemagbars
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get double magnitude bars.}
  \newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\else
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get single magnitude bars.}
  \newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\fi
\typeout{}
```

And here is the sample main document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[doublemagbars=true]{kvtest}
%\kvtestsetup{doublemagbars=true}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

The displacement is \( \vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\vec{r}} \).

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'd prefer to let the `doublemagbars` key redefine an internal macro instead of setting `\ifkvtest@doublemagbars`<sup>1</sup>, it doesn't seem possible to use `\define@keys` directly with keys processed by `kvoptions` (if anybody knows a possibility, please show me), so instead the following defines `\vec` and `\magvec` in such a way that they evaluate the conditionals and act accordingly. This way you can use `\kvtestsetup` everywhere you like (but the correct definition of `\vec` will only be available after `\begin{document}`, such that it respects other packages which might've redefined `\vec`).

Code of `kvtest.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{kvtest}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=kvtest,%
  prefix=kvtest@%
}%

\DeclareBoolOption[false]{doublemagbars}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{boldvectors}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\newcommand*{\kvtestsetup}{%
  \kvsetkeys{kvtest}%
}%

\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \let\kvtest@origvec\vec
    \renewcommand*\vec
      {%
        \ifkvtest@boldvectors
          \expandafter\symbfit
        \else
          \expandafter\kvtest@origvec
        \fi
      }%
  }

\newcommand\kvtest@lvert{\ifkvtest@doublemagbars\lVert\else\lvert\fi}
\newcommand\kvtest@rvert{\ifkvtest@doublemagbars\rVert\else\rvert\fi}

\newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\kvtest@lvert#1\right\kvtest@rvert}
```

Code of the example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[doublemagbars=true]{kvtest}
%\kvtestsetup{doublemagbars=true}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

The displacement is \( \vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\vec{r}} \).

\kvtestsetup{doublemagbars=false, boldvectors=true}
The displacement is \( \vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\vec{r}} \).

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>With other key=value solutions for package options, such as `pgfopts`, `l3keys2e`, or `exkpv-opt`, I would've defined a choice key that uses `\let\kvtest@lvert\lVert` and `\let\kvtest@rvert\rVert` for `doublemagbars=true` and `\let\kvtest@lvert\lvert` and `\let\kvtest@rvert\rvert` for `doublemagbars=false` instead (and something similar for `\vec`).

The following is an example how I would've done this with `expkv-opt` and `expkv-def`, the output and example document code is the same as above.

Code of `kvtest.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{kvtest}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def, expkv-opt}

% define the keys
\ekvdefinekeys{kvtest}
  {
    % doublemagbars is a choice accepting true or false, which will execute the
    % associated code
     choice doublemagbars = 
      {
         true  = \let\kvtest@lvert\lVert\let\kvtest@rvert\rVert
        ,false = \let\kvtest@lvert\lvert\let\kvtest@rvert\rvert
      }
    % if no value is specified, use =true
    ,default doublemagbars = true
    % execute the code associated with false now
    ,initial doublemagbars = false
    % same for boldvectors
    ,choice boldvectors =
      {
         true  = \def\kvtest@setupvec{\let\vec\symbfit}
        ,false = \let\kvtest@setupvec\@empty
      }
    ,default boldvectors = true
    ,initial boldvectors = false
  }

\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{kvtest} % options given to \documentclass
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{kvtest}  % options given to \usepackage

% at \begin{document}, save the current definition of \vec, run setupvec,
% which will be defined to use \symbfit if boldvectors=true was used, and
% redefine the boldvectors choices to directly do the redefinition from
% now on 
\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \let\kvtest@origvec\vec
    \kvtest@setupvec
    \ekvdefinekeys{kvtest}
      {
        choice boldvectors =
          {
             true  = \let\vec\symbfit
            ,false = \let\vec\kvtest@origvec
          }
      }%
  }

% define a shorthand macro to set keys for kvtest
\ekvsetdef\kvtestsetup{kvtest}

\newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\kvtest@lvert#1\right\kvtest@rvert}
```

Comment: I really like the flexibility of `expkv-opt` and `expkv-def`. I may switch!

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL while I'd love to hear you switched to `expkv` (and friends) I feel obliged to highlight that the same flexibility is possible with `l3keys2e` (`l3keys`) and `pgfopts` (`pgfkeys`).

Comment: I particularly would like the flexibility to set a default when no option is explicitly provided. I looked at `l3keys` and the syntax is confusing (I haven't taken the time to thoroughly understand it). I haven't looked at `pgfopts` yet, but will do so today.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL in `l3keys` you can set a default with the `.default:n` handler, so you'd use `\keys_define:nn { kvtest } { doublemagbars .default:n = true }`. In `pgfkeys` (`pgfopts` is just code to make `pgfkeys` available to parse package options, like `l3keys2e` is for `l3keys` and `expkv-opt` is for `expkv`) there is a similar named handler `.default` for this (so you'd use `\pgfkeys{/kvtest/.cd, doublemagbars/.default = true}`).

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL but go on and use `expkv` (I wrote that :), just note that its feature set is smaller than those of `l3keys` and `pgfkeys` (due to the parser being fully expandable, stuff like path-searching isn't trivial, also `expkv` doesn't use a tree-like structure for the keys, which makes parsing simpler, but again reduces possibilities; for simple key=value interfaces this won't be a problem, for things like done in Ti*k*Z this is a showstopper). If you also use `expkv-def` the difference isn't that giant (but still noticeable here and there).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still trying to understand why the booleans in my original question wouldn't respond so the `\kvtestsetup` command. I think it was the coding logic, but I'm not certain yet.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL because you don't define your macros to evaluate the conditionals, but instead you evaluate the conditionals in your package to define your macros, changing them after the definition of your macros won't change the definition of your macros.

Comment: The way you said that made it quite clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
\usepackage[doublemagbars=true]{kvtest}
```

then the boolean is set and the code

```
\ifkvtest@doublemagbars
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get double magnitude bars.}
  \newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\else
  \typeout{kvtest: You'll get single magnitude bars.}
  \newcommand{\magvec}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\fi
```

is executed when the package is read in.

If you do `\kvtestsetup{doublemagbars=true}`, the package code has already been read and you're just setting the boolean, but the definition of `\magvec` stays as it was before.

You may want to wrap the code depending on the booleans in `\AtBeginDocument`, so the action is performed when the booleans' values are known, assuming that `\kvtestsetup` is only used in the preamble.

Comment: Wrapping the block above in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` indeed worked. May I assume I can do this anywhere in the package where the options need to be evaluated for creating a new command?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of experimenting, I was finally able to find a way to make a setup command work. I used `\DeclareVoidOption{...}`, which assigns code that is executed when an option is provided. Now the problem is that at least one of the two options involved must be provided. This question ([Are dynamic defaults possible with kvoptions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279008/218142)) attempts to address this situation and I haven't tried that solution yet.

Here is the new MWE package file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{kvtest}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=kvtest,%
  prefix=kvtest@%
}%

\DeclareVoidOption{doublemagbars}{\let\mytestlvert\lVert\let\mytestrvert\rVert}
\DeclareVoidOption{singlemagbars}{\let\mytestlvert\lvert\let\mytestrvert\rvert}
\DeclareStringOption[stranger]{myname}[Joe]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\newcommand*{\kvtestsetup}{%
  \kvsetkeys{kvtest}%
}%

\newcommand*{\SayHello}{Hello, \kvtest@myname.}
\newcommand*{\magvec}[1]{\left\mytestlvert#1\right\mytestrvert}%
```

Here is the new MWE document file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlemagbars]{kvtest}
\begin{document}

The displacement is \( \Delta\vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\Delta\vec{r}} \).

\SayHello

\kvtestsetup{myname}
\SayHello

\kvtestsetup{myname=Jack}
\SayHello

\kvtestsetup{myname=Jill}
\SayHello

\kvtestsetup{doublemagbars}
The displacement is \( \Delta\vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\Delta\vec{r}} \).

\kvtestsetup{singlemagbars}
The displacement is \( \Delta\vec{r} \). The magnitude of the displacement is \( \magvec{\Delta\vec{r}} \).

\end{document}
```